# What can we say about the eigenvalues of a matrix with a complex trace and determinant?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In one of my classes, we showed that, given a 2x2 matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm$,

$\Re[\lambda\pm]<0 \iff \text{Tr}[\mathbf{A}]<0$ and $\det[\mathbf{A}]>0$

by computing the eigenvalues as

$\lambda_\pm = \text{Tr}[\mathbf{A}]\pm\sqrt{(\text{Tr}[\mathbf{A}])^2-4\det[\mathbf{A}]}$

It seemed to me that from the derivation, we were assuming the trace and determinant were both Real numbers; however, this isn't the general case.

Does this statement hold for $\text{Tr}[\mathbf{A}],\det[\mathbf{A}]\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It's not meaningful to say "trace less than zero" if the trace is complex and not real.

Comment: @Nathaniel D. Hoffman Eigenvalues here ($2\times 2$ matrix) are either real or complex conjugates. So trace is always real for that matrix.

Comment: There is nothing here that says what the entries of $\mathbf A$ are; if they are general complex numbers, then eigenvalues can be any pair of complex numbers, not just pairs of conjugates. If on the other hand entries are all real, then obviously so are trace and determinant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the first result by noting that trace is real in the case of a $2\times 2$ matrix since the characteristic polynomial has either real roots or 2 complex conjugate roots.
The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues so again will be positive in any case (you can check) if real parts of the eigenvalues are positive.
Your question then maybe should be if the statement holds for a matrix of size $n\times n $, or for which $n $?

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn't even thinking of it that way, but I guess one thing that still kind of bugs me is, isn't the trace also defined as the sum of the diagonal elements? Couldn't I have one element be like "4" and another be "3+5i" and then have a complex trace? Or is that a less general way to calculate the trace?

Comment: @Nathaniel D.Hoffman You said the result is fir $2\times 2$ matrices. If a $2\times 2$ matruc has a complex eigenvalue $\lambda$ then the conjugate of $\lambda $ is also an eigenvalue and there are no others. Add these two eigenvalues now and obviously the sum is $2*Re (\lambda) $.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Since there is no hypothesis that matrix entries are real, the statement about complex conjugate eigenvalues is wrong, and so is this answer..